# Ping a server and output based on how long ping took

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$Servers = "8.8.8.8"
$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $TimeStart.AddMinutes(1)

Do {
    Foreach($s in $Servers) {
    $Timeout = 1
    $Ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    $Response = $Ping.Send($s,$Timeout)
    $Response.Status
    $TimeNow = Get-Date
    }
}
Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
```

But it seems to run too often. Ideally I would like a ping to take place for every second, for a minute, and if the ping takes longer than 5 milliseconds, log 'TimedOut' and anything below 5 milliseconds to log 'Success'. Also, outputting the date would be useful too.

How would I manipulate this code to achieve this?

Comment: `Test-Connection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script uses Test-Connection with `-Count 1` and  configurable Delay between tests and also a treshold to define Success/Timeout.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\13\SO_51327101.ps1

$Servers = "8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4","62.220.18.8","89.246.64.8" 

$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $TimeStart.AddMinutes(2)

$Treshold = 12
$DelayMS = 1500

Do {
    Foreach($Server in $Servers) {
        $Response = Test-Connection $Server -Count 1
        $Status = 'Success '
        If ($Response.ResponseTime -gt $Treshold){$Status = 'TimedOut'}
        "[{0}] {1} Server: {2,15} Responsetime: {3,3} ms" -f `
            (Get-Date -f yyyyMMddHHmmss),
            $Status,
            $Server,
            $Response.ResponseTime
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $DelayMS
} Until ((Get-Date) -ge $TimeEnd)
```

Sample output

```
[20180713172651] TimedOut Server:     89.246.64.8 Responsetime:  13 ms
[20180713172653] Success  Server:         8.8.8.8 Responsetime:  12 ms
[20180713172653] Success  Server:         8.8.4.4 Responsetime:  12 ms
[20180713172653] Success  Server:     62.220.18.8 Responsetime:   7 ms
[20180713172653] TimedOut Server:     89.246.64.8 Responsetime:  13 ms
```

Comment: This works perfectly :) is there a way to output this to a file at the end?

Comment: Simply redirect output to a file appending `>> '.\file.log` or pipe to `Out-File '.\file.log' -Append -Encoding ascii`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Test-Connection` to do this.  Here's one way, with slight modifications to get the additional info you want:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName $servers -Delay 1 -Count 60 |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value (Get-Date) -PassThru |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value $(if($_.ResponseTime -gt 5){"Failed"}else{"Succeeded"}) -PassThru
```

This will ping each server in `$servers` once per second for 60 seconds, and output the standard objects, with two new properties: `Date` (datetime of the ping) and `Status` (did it succeed or fail?)

You can capture these, display them onscreen or send to file.  For example to log the data by saving to CSV, you could just append the following:

`| Export-Csv .\ping.csv`

The CSV will contain more information than you need, so you can either be selective in what you export, or simply ignore what you don't want and use the parts you do.

**EDIT: Displaying the custom properties**

To see the custom properties in the console, append the following:

`| Format-Table PsComputerName, Date, ResponseTime, Status`

Comment: This seems to just Test-Connection and not output Failed or Succeeded or the date :(

Comment: As the output is the same object type (with modifications), the default display will be the same as normal.  You will need to use custom output formatting.  I have edited my answer to show how to see the additional information.

Comment: This is probably the best way you can do this

Comment: IF this answer worked for you please mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

This one uses Workflow to allow for parallel pings. It also takes into account that that System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping timeout isnt exact when it comes to low millisecond use. I suggest working BoxDogs Answer since its the most inline with powershell standards. But I wanted to join in the fun and learning.

```
workflow AdvPing([string[]]$Servers, [timespan]$RunTimeLength, [timespan]$Freqency, [timespan]$PingTimeout){
    foreach -parallel ($Server in $Servers)
    {
        $Runtime = (get-date).Add($RunTimeLength)
        $CurrentDate = get-date
        $Timeout = $PingTimeout
        $Ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

        while($CurrentDate -le $RunTime){
            $Response = ""
            $ResponseMessage = ""
            $CurrentFreqency = (Get-Date).add($Freqency)
            try{
                $Response = $Ping.Send($Server,$Timeout.TotalMilliseconds)
                if(($Response.RoundtripTime -gt $PingTimeout.Milliseconds) -and ($Response.Status -like "Success")){
                    $ResponseMessage = "TimeOut"
                }else{
                    $ResponseMessage = $Response.Status
                }
                $Reply = New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    Server = $Server
                    Response = $ResponseMessage
                    Date = $(get-date).DateTime
                    Time = $Response.RoundtripTime
                    Exception = $null
                }
            }catch{
                $Reply = New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    Server = $Server
                    Response = "No Host"
                    Date = $(get-date).DateTime
                    Time = $null
                    Exception = $_
                }
            }
            $Reply

            $CurrentDate = Get-Date
            [timespan]$Wait = $CurrentFreqency - $CurrentDate
            try{
                sleep -Milliseconds $Wait.TotalMilliseconds
            }catch{}
        }
    }
}

$Servers = @("8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4", "StackOverflow.com","243.42.432.44")
advping -Servers $Servers -RunTimeLength ([TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(60)) -Freqency ([TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(1)) -PingTimeout ([TimeSpan]::FromMilliseconds(5)) | format-table Date,Server,Response,Time
```

The output will look like

```
Date                             Server            Response Time
----                             ------            -------- ----
Friday, July 13, 2018 2:53:37 PM 243.42.432.44     No Host      
Friday, July 13, 2018 2:53:37 PM StackOverflow.com TimeOut  15  
Friday, July 13, 2018 2:53:37 PM 8.8.4.4           Success  2   
Friday, July 13, 2018 2:53:37 PM 8.8.8.8           Success  2   
Friday, July 13, 2018 2:53:38 PM 243.42.432.44     No Host      
Friday, July 13, 2018 2:53:38 PM StackOverflow.com TimeOut  15  
Friday, July 13, 2018 2:53:38 PM 8.8.4.4           Success  2   
Friday, July 13, 2018 2:53:38 PM 8.8.8.8           Success  2
```